# Detect a changed password in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-signals

When a user changes their password, I want to send a signal so that I can do some stuff on some models.

How can I create this signal?

I've looked at the `post_save` signal for User:

```
post_save.connect(user_updated, sender=User)
```

However, there doesn't seem to be anything in there for me to check if the password was changed:

```
def user_updated(sender, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs) # {'created': False, 'raw': False, 'instance': <User: 100002>, 'update_fields': None, 'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x7ff8862f03c8>, 'using': 'default'}
```

I also see that there is a `password_change_done` auth view, but I'm not sure how I'd use it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-views

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal. `kwargs['instance']` will contain the
updated password and you can get the old password with `User.objects.get(id=
user.id).password`

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def user_updated(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.get('instance', None)
    if user:
        new_password = user.password
        try:
            old_password = User.objects.get(pk=user.pk).password
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            old_password = None
        if new_password != old_password:
        # do what you need here
```

Comment: Note that this well detect changes in the salt or hashing algorithm as a password change. If you need to detect just the actual password changes, you need to hook into the view and check the new password before it is hashed.

Comment: When could the salt or hash alg change? An upgrade scenario?

Comment: @43Tesseracts newer versions of Django update the password algorithm / rounds used, and when users log in it updates the password to use the newer version

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a custom user model you could presumably intersect the `set_password()` call to set a flag on the instance, and then pick up its presence within a signal:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    def set_password(self, password):
        super(User, self).set_password(password)
        self._set_password = True

    @classmethod
    def user_saved(cls, sender, instance, **kwargs):
        if getattr(instance, '_set_password', False):
            # Take action


post_save.connect(User.user_saved, sender=User)
```

Comment: If you don't mind involving implementation details, you can just check `instance._password` instead. It's always `None` initially, and becomes the raw password if one is set.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution so you don't have to compare the password hashes, that can be different even if the password is the same.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=get_user_model())
def detect_password_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Checks if the user changed his password
    """
    if instance._password is None:
        return

    try:
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=instance.id)
    except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
        return

    print("password changed")
    # if you get here, the user changed his password
```